# Перехват нажатия клавиш Power, Sleep, Wake клавиатуры

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

Для глобального перехвата нажатия клавиш клавиатуры использую клавиатурный хук, установка которого производится из dll:

```
kb_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardMsgProc, hInstance, NULL);

static LRESULT WINAPI KeyboardMsgProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(code >= HC_ACTION)
    return 1;

return CallNextHookEx(kb_hook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Это работает нормально, перехватываются все клавиши клавиатуры, кроме **Power**, **Sleep** и **Wake**. Вопрос - как и чем отслеживать нажатие указанных кнопок?